# Creating a LinkingObjects property in RealmSwift by using multiple-level properties

Tags: swift, realm, realm-cocoa

According to the [Realm documentation for v0.102.0](https://realm.io/docs/swift/0.102.0/), this is how you create an inverse relationship:

#### Person

```
class Person: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

#### Dog (v1)

```
class Dog: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
}
```

Suppose that we have another class, called `DogFood`, and we want to create an inverse relationship called `buyers` that tracks which instances of `Person` have a `Dog` that eats that instance of `DogFood`. We could try the following:

#### Dog (v2)

```
class Dog: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let favoriteFoods = List<DogFood>
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
}
```

#### DogFood

```
class DogFood: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    let buyers = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs.favoriteFoods")
}
```

However, this throws the following error: `Property 'dogs.favoriteFoods' declared as origin of linking objects property 'buyers' does not exist.`

Is there another way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Submitted issue to the Realm-Cocoa repo on GitHub: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3558. It was acknowledged as an enhancement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a filter, with the caveat that the `DogFood` object we need to query about needs to be part of a `Realm`.

The code would go as follows:

```
class DogFood: Object {
    // ... other property declarations
    var items: Results<Person> {
        if let realm = self.realm {
            return realm.objects(Person).filter(NSPredicate(format: "ANY dogs.favoriteFoods.id == %@", self.id))
        } else {
            return RealmSwift.List<Person>().filter("1 != 1")
        }
    }
}
```

The property `realm` is of type `Realm?` and comes into the picture through inheritance from `Object`. It points towards the realm that a particular `Object` instance is in and returns `nil` if not assigned to one. If that is the case, we force the property `items` to return an empty set of `Results<Person>`.